# How to 'center' a Histogram

Tags: histograms

How can a generate a histogram so the peak of the distribution is at x=0?

I want to center these histograms for comparison

```
(*k=2*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {2}], {1000}]

(*k=4*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {4}], {1000}]

(*k=10*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {10}], {1000}]

(*k=50*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {50}], {1000}]

(*k=100*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {100}], {1000}]

(*k=10 000*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {10000}], {1000}]

(*k=100 000*)
Histogram@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {100000}], {1000}]
```

edit: range was incorrect

edit 2: Got it!
    Histogram[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1],k]]

Comment: Are you sure `Histogram` is what you're after, vs say `BarChart` or a straight `Plot`? In addition, not clear what you mean by "Peak at x=0". A `Histogram` will have the "edge" of the "bars" at bin boundaries. You could massage the table results and bin specification to fake that (somewhat), but might be better to elucidate *what* you're trying to accomplish, might elicit a better solution... oops, you updated again as I was typing. If you answered your own question, consider posting it as such.

Comment: I'm a new user so it won't let me post an answer. Sorry about that!

Comment: No worries, you'll get that soon, so if appropriate it's standard to self-answer. Read the doc's re: distribution functions, some cool ways you can accomplish what (I think) you're doing...

Answer (score 1):

When wanting to do costum things with histograms, I find it's often best to use the functions [`HistogramDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramDistribution.html) and [`HistogramList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HistogramList.html). Which give you respectively a distribution object and a list defining the histogram. Below I've shown how i would compare the distributions, note that I'm using a line plot rather than the more appropriate boxchart since it makes it easier to compare the curves.

```
histogramMeanLine[{binEdges_, y_}] := {Mean /@ Partition[binEdges, 2, 1], y} // Transpose
centerPeak[v_] := {v[[1 ;;, 1]] - First@Last@SortBy[v, Last], v[[1 ;;, 2]]} // Transpose
myHist[v_] := ListLinePlot[centerPeak@histogramMeanLine@HistogramList@v, Filling->0,   PlotMarkers->Automatic]
```

Which then allow you do do the plot you wanted with:

```
SeedRandom[54298]
Table[myHist@Table[Total@RandomInteger[1, {n}], {1000}],
               {n, {2,4,10,50,100,10000,100000}}] // Show
```

Comment: jVincent, you seem to have stopped posting.  I just wanted to let you know that it hasn't gone unnoticed and that I miss your contributions.  I hope you soon find time and interest to continue your participation.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot centre a histogram: the histogram just represents the data.  What you can "centre" is the data the histogram is built from.

Instead of

```
Histogram[data]
```

use

```
Histogram[data - Mean[data]]
```